# Why a user has sound working in Debian 11 and other not?

Tags: linux, debian, audio, gnu, firmware

In Debian 11 I have two users in a laptop Lenovo Ideapad S145.

One user has the sound working very well -- I don't know if it is a valid info but the user is in sudoers group. The other one gets Dummy Output in Sound Output Configurations.

Why one user gets audio and other doesn't, if the driver is installed and working properly for the first one?

Some possible relevant info (in console from the user sound is working):

Outuput of `lcpci | grep -i audio`:

```
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller (rev 30)
```

Output of `sudo lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Audio`:

```
00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller [8086:34c8] (rev 30)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller [17aa:3840]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci
```

Output of `sudo lsmod | grep snd_hda_intel`:

```
snd_hda_intel          57344  6
snd_intel_dspcfg       28672  3 snd_hda_intel,snd_sof_pci,snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_hda_codec         176128  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_soc_hdac_hda
snd_hda_core          110592  9 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_sof_intel_hda
snd_pcm               143360  11 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,soundwire_intel,snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_hda_core
snd                   110592  20 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm
```

Output of `aplay -l`:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC236 Analog [ALC236 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 11: HDMI 5 [HDMI 5]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 12: HDMI 6 [HDMI 6]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Comment: Are both users in the audio group?

Comment: The problem was exactly that. The other user wasn't in audio group. If you want you can answer and I will approve. Thanks @currawong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that all users are in the audio group in the /etc/group file.